# Linear programming/MIP setting up sum of conditional constraints?

Tags: r, constraints, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, lpsolve

I'm trying to set up MIP problem using LpSolve and I'm at a loss on how to set it up.

We are trying to allocate resources to various investments, to maximize revenue, subject to a budget constraint. Each business is located in a particular state, and **We also have to spread our allocations across 5 states** (this is the one that's causing me issues). My current linear equations are this:

Objective function: maximize following where X<sub>i</sub> represents the number of dollars allocated to
i<sup>th</sup> business, and R<sub>i</sub> represents revenue generated by the i<sup>th</sup> business

> X<sub>1</sub> * R<sub>1</sub> +....+ X<sub>35</sub> * R<sub>35</sub>

Subject to the constraint:

> X<sub>1</sub> * C<sub>1</sub> +....+ X<sub>35</sub> * C<sub>35</sub> <= 1,000,000

Where  C<sub>i</sub> represents the costs of the i<sup>th</sup> business. Setting this objective function and constraint matrix is very easy. However each business is located in some state, and what I need to do is setup a constraint that we must allocate to business in at least 5 states.

What I initially considered was a set of constraints where each state was represented as a row: so if this row represents the state of California for instance:

> X<sub>1</sub> * 1 +....+ X<sub>2</sub> * 1 + X<sub>3</sub> *0 + X<sub>35</sub> * 1   <= Some Constraint

Then each business in California is assigned a value of 1, then this would give me the sum of $s (from the X<sub>i</sub> assigned to each business) allocated to California. I could do this for all states, but that doesn't quite get me what I want as I thought about it mroe. I could constrain each state using this methodology, but what I want is something that lets me assign `Unique_States >5`

But this doesn't quite get me what I want. What I really want is something that gives me a sum of total number of states "used".

Is this even possible?

I've spent a while trying to rack my brain on how to do this but I can't quite figure it out.

There's one other questions like this on SO, but I couldn't follow any of the answers:
[LpSolve R conditional constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351725/lpsolve-r-conditional-constraint)

This question is awfully similar albeit a totally different context, but I couldn't follow it and I don't have enough reputation to ask any questions.

If anyone could give any sort of guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a skeleton of your model in `pyomo`.  This is basically a "Knapsack Problem" with a twist (the min number of states reqt.).

#### Code

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from collections import defaultdict

# some data...  this could be from dictionary (as below) or file read or ....

#               name                 state  C   R
investments = { 'Burger Joint':     ('CA', 1.2, 3.1),
                'car wash':         ('CA', 1.1, 2.6),
                'gem store':        ('NV', 1.0, 2.5),
                'warehouse':        ('UT', 1.2, 3.6)}

budget = 10
min_investment = 1
min_states_to_use = 2

states = {v[0] for v in investments.values()}
investments_by_state = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in investments.items():
    investments_by_state[v[0]].append(k)

# set up the model

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# SETS

m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=investments.keys())
m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=list(states))
# the below is an "indexed set" which is indexed by STATE and contains the 
# subset of I within that state
m.IS = pyo.Set(m.S, within=m.I, initialize=investments_by_state)

# PARAMETERS
m.cost = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize={k:v[1] for k, v in investments.items()})
m.rev  = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize={k:v[2] for k, v in investments.items()})

# VARIABLES
m.X = pyo.Var(m.I, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)  # amount invested in i
m.Y = pyo.Var(m.S, domain=pyo.Binary)            # 1 if state y has an investment

# OBJECTIVE
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.X[i]*m.rev[i] for i in m.I), sense=pyo.maximize)

# CONSTRAINTS
# stay in budget...
m.C1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.X[i]*m.cost[i] for i in m.I) <= budget)

# connect indicator Y to X...
def state_invest(m, s):
    return m.Y[s] * min_investment <= sum(m.X[i] for i in m.IS[s])
m.C2 = pyo.Constraint(m.S, rule=state_invest)

# use needed number of states
m.C3 = pyo.Constraint(expr=sum(m.Y[s] for s in m.S) >= min_states_to_use)

m.pprint()  # <-- show the whole model

# instantiate a solver and solve...
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
result = solver.solve(m)
print(result)

m.X.display()  # <-- "display" substitutes in the variable values
m.Y.display()
```

#### Output

```
3 Set Declarations
    I : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {'Burger Joint', 'car wash', 'gem store', 'warehouse'}
    IS : Size=3, Index=S, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
         CA :     1 :      I :    2 : {'Burger Joint', 'car wash'}
         NV :     1 :      I :    1 : {'gem store',}
         UT :     1 :      I :    1 : {'warehouse',}
    S : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'CA', 'NV', 'UT'}

2 Param Declarations
    cost : Size=4, Index=I, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key          : Value
        Burger Joint :   1.2
            car wash :   1.1
           gem store :   1.0
           warehouse :   1.2
    rev : Size=4, Index=I, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key          : Value
        Burger Joint :   3.1
            car wash :   2.6
           gem store :   2.5
           warehouse :   3.6

2 Var Declarations
    X : Size=4, Index=I
        Key          : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        Burger Joint :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
            car wash :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
           gem store :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
           warehouse :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    Y : Size=3, Index=S
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
         CA :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
         NV :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary
         UT :     0 :  None :     1 : False :  True : Binary

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : maximize : 3.1*X[Burger Joint] + 2.6*X[car wash] + 2.5*X[gem store] + 3.6*X[warehouse]

3 Constraint Declarations
    C1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                                                                    : Upper : Active
        None :  -Inf : 1.2*X[Burger Joint] + 1.1*X[car wash] + X[gem store] + 1.2*X[warehouse] :  10.0 :   True
    C2 : Size=3, Index=S, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body                                    : Upper : Active
         CA :  -Inf : Y[CA] - (X[Burger Joint] + X[car wash]) :   0.0 :   True
         NV :  -Inf :                    Y[NV] - X[gem store] :   0.0 :   True
         UT :  -Inf :                    Y[UT] - X[warehouse] :   0.0 :   True
    C3 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                  : Upper : Active
        None :   2.0 : Y[CA] + Y[NV] + Y[UT] :  +Inf :   True

11 Declarations: I S IS cost rev X Y obj C1 C2 C3

Problem: 
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: -29.5
  Upper bound: -29.5
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 5
  Number of variables: 7
  Number of binary variables: 3
  Number of integer variables: 3
  Number of nonzeros: 4
  Sense: maximize
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  User time: -1.0
  System time: 0.0
  Wallclock time: 0.0
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
  Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
      Number of bounded subproblems: 0
      Number of created subproblems: 0
    Black box: 
      Number of iterations: 0
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 0.014362096786499023
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0

X : Size=4, Index=I
    Key          : Lower : Value     : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    Burger Joint :     0 :       1.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
        car wash :     0 :       0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
       gem store :     0 :       0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
       warehouse :     0 : 7.3333333 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
Y : Size=3, Index=S
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
     CA :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
     NV :     0 :   0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
     UT :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
[Finished in 696ms]
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough. This has been bugging me for 10 days now, thank you very very very much, I really appreciate your generosity in the answers. Above and beyond anything I could have asked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 general approaches here that might help.  Caveat:  I don't know `LpSolve` syntax and I don't know how you would (or could) express these in `r`/`LpSolve` syntax.  Aside:  Are you open to a different framework?  There are several LP frameworks in `python` that would make this very easy to set up...  Anyhow...  with some pseudocode...

In both of the approaches below, you will need to implement a binary "indicator variable" that indicates whether a state has been used.  This also assumes there is some logical "min investment" value to prevent spreading something like 0.00001 in a particular investment

```
S = {CA, NV, UT, ...}  set of states
Y[s ∈ S] ∈ {0, 1}      binary indicator
```

Approach 1:  Make subsets of your investment options by state and index those by state.  Then you could sum over the whole set as needed

```
I = {1, 2, ..., 35}              set of investment options
X[i ∈ I] ∈ {non-negative reals}  the amount invested in i
IS = {CA: {1, 5, 10,...}, NV: {2, 4, 15,...} , ...}   subsets by state

for each s ∈ S:
    Y[s] * min_investment <= ∑ X[IS[s]]   # constrain Y to be less than state sum

∑Y[s] >= 5
```

Approach 2:  double-index your investments by [state, i] and then you can sum over either the states or investments (`I`).

```
X[s, i] <= 0   constrain for all applicable combos that are illegal
for s ∈ S:
    Y[s] * min_investment <= ∑ (X[s, i] for all i ∈ I)
∑Y[s] >= 5
```

It appears that `LpSolve` wants a big matrix for constraints, so either of these might be difficult in that framework, but they are straightforward in other frameworks.  Perhaps somebody w/ deeper experience in `LpSolve` can suggest syntax.

Comment: More than happy to investigate other models other than lpSolve. I looked into glpk but it seemed to have awfully similar syntax to lpSolve. Your pseudocode that begins with "for each s in S" is absolutely perfect, I had no idea you could use syntax like that in a linear optimizer since I've only ever used lpSolve which only allows numerical matrix inputs (from what I can tell)

Comment: Do you have packages/libraries you could recommend? Googling suggests PULP might be a popular one, is that one that would work similar to the pseudocode you laid out above?

Comment: I use both `pulp` and `pyomo`.  I prefer `pyomo`.  It is more expressive and the syntax is clearer, IMHO.  Both use fairly straightforward python syntax to build optimization models.  Pyomo does NOT include a solver, but there are several free ones you can install and use any with pyomo.  GLPK, CBC are both good (free) solvers for LP.  I've posted quite a few answers in both pyomo and pulp tags....  take a look at some of my answers for ideas.  I'll code you an example for your problem above in pyomo......stby...